# Does a polygon loaded from a KML contain a given Lat/Lng in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a KML file which contains a polygon. I am wanting to write a simple application which will give a true/false result on whether a lat/lng is inside of that polygon.

For whatever reason, this seems to be more difficult that it sounds, as the google.maps.KmlLayer seems to be very limited with the functions it offers.

I am aware that a non-KML map has a "containsLocation()" function which does exactly what I need, however, the KML layer contains no such function

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure how you are using the KML file however I would suggest the following approach:

1. Parse your KML file (Many libraries available for many languages)
2. Use the parsed KML data to render your Polygon using the Google Maps API (i.e. reconstruct you KML polygon in Google Maps with the Google Maps methods)
3. Use the Google Maps API `containslocation()` method to check whether a co-ordinate is inside the Polygon

The Google Maps API has a large feature set so by doing this you could incorporate some of their methods, i.e. You click on the map and the program tells you wether the point you have just clicked is inside the polygon or not. Have a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation), I suspect this is what you want to accomplish (or at least similar to it).

**Edit:** By parse I mean decode the KML

Comment: If my answer helped please consider adding an upvote.